# Customized Buil-In element without a Constructor/Super call, and the Apple future

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I am squeezing out the last bytes from my `svg-icon` **Customized Built-In *HTMLImage*Element**

#### Some detailed questions:

- What is the latest news on (the future of) Apple/Safari & Customized Buil-In Elements?
  is there a developer discussion to read up on somewhere?
- will I run into trouble for not using a `constructor()` and thus no `super()` call ?
- Same for not using a `connectedCallback()` ?

Bonus question:

- the `attributeChangedCallback` gets a FOURTH parameter... undocumented
  Anyone know more about this?

  The snippet shows a P4 `object=null` in all 4 browsers: Chrome, Edge, FireFox, Opera

```js
customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLImageElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["color"];
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name,oldValue,newValue,P4,P5) {
    console.log('P4:',typeof P4,P4,'P5:',typeof P5,P5);
    this.src = `data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 8 8' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>`
                +`<circle cx='4' cy='4' r='4' fill='${newValue}'/></svg>`
  }
}, { extends: "img" })
```

```css
img{
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<img is="svg-icon" color="red">
<img is="svg-icon" color="green">
<img is="svg-icon" color="blue">
```

Comment: #1: never #2: AFAIK no #3: idem #bonus: the namespace (of the attribute)

Comment:  Apple, now I have to add 31 GZipped Bytes to the final single-file (*making it a challenge to stay under 999+1 bytes (gzipped)*)

Comment: @Supersharp, does Safari error out when trying to create a CBIE? I never touch those Apple devices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *yes*, evolving standards discussed in https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents
2. *yes*, not specifying a constructor in a derived class will automatically inherit the parent constructor from the prototype chain (ultimately defaulting to an empty method)
3. *yes*, all webcomponent lifecycle callback functions are optional
4. *yes*, the signature is `attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue, attrNamespace)` as in:

```
icon.setAttribute('color', 'red'); //'color',null,'red',null
icon.setAttributeNS('foo', 'color', 'red'); //'color',null,'red','foo'
```

Comment: That was a question from 2.5 years ago, but your answers are correct